# why does this code using == and | operators result in TRUE

Tags: r, operators

Why does this return TRUE:

```
15 == 1|2|10
```

I thought it would be asking is 15 the same as 1 or 2 or 10 which would result in FALSE.

Comment: No, you'd need to do `15 == 1 | 15 == 2 | 15 == 10`. Or maybe use `%in%`.

Comment: You statement is equivalent to `(15 == 1)|2|10` See `help(Syntax)`

Answer (score 5):

If you look at how R parses code, this

```
15 == 1|2|10
```

is the same as

```
(((15 == 1) | 2) | 10)
```

Where `|` will return TRUE if one of the values is not FALSE (or 0). So `15==1` is `FALSE` but `FALSE | 2` is `TRUE` since 2 is not 0. And then `TRUE | 10` is also TRUE. So

```
( FALSE | TRUE) | TRUE)  == TRUE
```

Do not use `|` to match one of multiple values. Use `%in%` to test if a value is contained in a vector of values.

```
15 %in% c(1, 2, 10)
```